# Virtual paint() is not getting called while drawing Polyline

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am new to Qt, and wants to write code to change Qt's default selection behaviour. So I am trying to override virtual paint method. But paint method is not getting called.
Below code, just print the polyline and paint() tries to change its selection behaviour.

polyline.h

```
class Polyline : public QGraphicsPathItem
{
public:
    Polyline();
    virtual void paint (QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override
    {
        auto copied_option = *option;
        copied_option.state &= ~QStyle::State_Selected;
        auto selected = option->state & QStyle::State_Selected;
        QGraphicsPathItem::paint(painter, &copied_option, widget);
        if (selected)
        {
            painter->save();
            painter->setBrush(Qt::red);
            painter->setPen(QPen(option->palette.windowText(), 5, Qt::DotLine));
            painter->drawPath(shape());
            painter->restore();
        }
    }
    QGraphicsPathItem* drawPolyline();
};
```

polyline.cpp

```
#include "polyline.h"

Polyline::Polyline()
{}

QGraphicsPathItem* Polyline::drawPolyline()
{
    QPolygonF polygon;
    polygon<< QPointF (150,450) << QPointF (350,450) <<QPointF (350,200) << QPointF (250,100)<<QPointF (150,200);

    QPainterPath pPath;

    pPath.addPolygon(polygon);
    QGraphicsPathItem* new_item = new QGraphicsPathItem(pPath);
    new_item->setPen(QPen(QColor("red"), 5));
    new_item->setPath(pPath);
    new_item->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
    return new_item;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "polyline.h"
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsView view;
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    view.setScene(&scene);

    Polyline p;
    QGraphicsPathItem* poly = p.drawPolyline();
    scene.addItem(poly);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Nowhere in the `drawPolyline` function do you create a `Polyline` object. You don't add any `Polyline` object to the UI in any other way. Why should your `Polyline::paint` function be called?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : Sorry but I am not able to do what you have suggested. Can you show, how I should do ?

Comment: Perhaps you should do `QGraphicsPathItem* new_item = new Polyline(pPath);` instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : It is working. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't create any `Polyline` object and attach it to the window or a widget.

As such there's just no `Polyline` object to call the `paint` function on.

A simple solution it to have your `drawPolyline` function create a `Polyline` object instead of the `QGraphicsPathItem` object you create now:

```
QGraphicsPathItem* new_item = new Polyline(pPath);
```

Remember to modify the `Polyline` constructor to take the path, and forward it to the base `QGraphicsPathItem` class.

---

Another improvement is to realize that `drawPolyline` doesn't really need to be a member function at all. And that it's rather badly named. I would suggest you define it as a source-file local function, renamed as `createPolyline` instead:

```
namespace
{
    QGraphicsPathItem* createPolyline()
    {
        // The body of your `drawPolyline` function
        // With the fix mentioned above
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then use this function instead:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsView view;
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    view.setScene(&scene);

    scene.addItem(createPolyline());
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```